# Django: DetailView and multiple slugs

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have an issue with my DetailView. I want to make sure **both** values are in the url string and then want to display the page. However I am always receiving this error here:

```
KeyError at /orders/ticket/ug2dc78agz-1/d04fkjmo37/
'order_reference'
```

**views.py**

```
class TicketView(DetailView):
    model = Attendee
    template_name = 'orders/ticket_view.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Attendee.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=self.kwargs['order_reference'],
        ).filter(
            access_key=self.kwargs['access_key'],
        )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'ticket/<slug:ticket_reference>/<slug:access_key>/',
        TicketView.as_view(),
        name='ticket'
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you are trying to access `self.kwargs['order_reference']`, but you don't use `order_reference` in the `path()`.

Your `path()` uses,

```
'ticket/<slug:ticket_reference>/<slug:access_key>/'
```

therefore you can use `self.kwargs['ticket_reference']` and `self.kwargs['access_key']`.

Since your path does not contain `slug` or `pk`, Django will not know how to fetch the object for the detail view. I would override `get_object` instead of `get_queryset`:

```
def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(
        Attendee,
        order__order_reference=self.kwargs['slug:ticket_reference'],
        access_key=self.kwargs['access_key'],
    )
```

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you! Made the code even shorter.

Comment: order__order_reference__iexact = self.kwargs['access_key'].replace('-', ' ') if there can be small & big letters and space in reference field. And use Attendee.objects.filter(id = self.object.id) to avoid other reference fields to work instead of only specific one in the link.

Answer (score 1):

You have `ticket_reference` url variable, but in view using `order_reference`. You should rename it:

```
class TicketView(DetailView):
    model = Attendee
    template_name = 'orders/ticket_view.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Attendee.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=self.kwargs['ticket_reference'],
        ).filter(
            access_key=self.kwargs['access_key'],
        )
```

Comment: Ahh yes! That solved it! It actually was `ticket_reference`. I just took `order__order_reference` from my OrderListView and forgot to change it. Thank you!